# How to search a table using keywords through javascript? The search only finds the form based on the wording on the existing table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to search a table using keywords through javascript? My search only finds the form based on the wording in the existing table. Would it be possible to add keywords to display certain results? For example, if I search for "Apple", it should display the same results as if I searched for "ABC". See my table below.
Note that I do not have access to update table. I can only add keywords through javascript.

https://codepen.io/magic12/pen/QWmvGBX

HTML:

```
<p><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search forms list" title="Search forms list"></p>
<table class="table_brdr" id="myTable">
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th><strong>Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>abc</td>
<td>xyz</td>
<td>03/30/2017</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>test12</td>
<td>https://www.yahoo.com/ </td>
<td>03/30/2017</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th> New Column</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>abctd <td>
<td>09/30/2019</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th> New Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>abctd </td>
<td>06/30/2019</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

CSS

```
table.table_brdr td {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border: none;
}

table.table_brdr th {
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  color: black;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color#D3D3D3;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
  const userInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase();
  const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
  for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    const rowTextContent = tableRows[i].innerText.toUpperCase();
    tableRows[i].style.display = rowTextContent.toUpperCase().includes(userInput) ? "" : "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please put all your code in a snippet demo using the editor. No need to send us to Codepen. Be sure to use the Tidy button to properly format.

Comment: You can do this by creating an array of keywords - for example `[ { word: "ABC", keyword: "Apple" } ]`. Then just create a search function that loops through these and checks for any matches for either the word or the keyword.

Comment: @Dimitar Veljanovski,  Do you have an example I can look at?